# Attempt to de-reference a null object building list in loop

Tags: apex, tasks

What could be going on here? I've got a method that checks for the existence of a duplicate-kind record like so:

```
public Boolean tasktNotSaved(Lead lead, String subject, String body) {
    Task[] matchingTask;
    for (Task possibleMatch: [SELECT Description, Subject FROM Task WHERE WhoId = :lead.Id AND Subject = :subject AND OwnerId = :lead.OwnerId]) {
        if (possibleMatch != null && possibleMatch.Description != null && possibleMatch.Description.contains(body)) {
            matchingTasks.add(possibleMatch);
        }
    }
    return (matchingTasks == null || matchingTasks.size() == 0);
}
```

I get my exception on line 27, which above is the `matchingTasks.add(possibleMatch);` line. I think I've debugged all the variables involved, and none of them are `null`. What am I missing?

Comment: Deleted my answer because I'm second guessing myself now, but should you be looking for the `WhatID` not the `WhoID`

Comment: Actually if you debug `Task.WhoId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()` you get `(Contact, Lead)`. Even if there were no results, it would be an empty list, not `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `matchingTasks` variable is in fact `null` because you have declared it but not initialized it. Change your declaration line to:

```
List<Task> matchingTasks = new List<Task>();
```

Comment: OMG, thank-you. I was tearing my hair out.

Comment: @CD-RUM Glad you got it worked out. If this post led you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question.

Comment: Yep, just waiting until the timer lets me accept. Thanks again.